# Configure git to always ignore certain types of change

Tags: git

So the project I'm working on unavoidably has certain changes within files that I do not wish to add to the codebase. These ignorable changes are very recognisable and I'm happy to blindly exclude them.

They look something like

`-      'weight' => (some number),`

`+      'weight' => (some other number),`

and occur with varying indentation across multiple files.

Is there a way for Git to ignore/filter out/scrub these specific changes without my having to `git add -p` constantly?

Answer (score 0):

You can use git filters (see `gitattributes(5)`). There you can define two programs "clean" and "smudge". The task of former is to take the file from your checkout and turn it into the blob that is going to be checked in. You could write such a program to replace the relevant numbers with default values. The task of the other program is to take a blob and return the file to be written to your checkout. It could look up the intended values and restore them into the blob. If you are careful to never check these files out, implementing the clean filter may be enough to suit your need. The gory details are all in the manual page referenced above.